# Jquery: função buscar se nome arquivo contém e substituir

Tags: jquery

Função para substituir src, caso contenha determinada palavra. Ex:

```html
<li class"none">
    <img src="/img/aqui-pode-mudar-exemplo.png?v=123456" alt="Imagem">
</li>
```

Função para buscar nas classes "none" se o SRC contem "exemplo" e substituir. No caso alterar todo o src.

Outra possibilidade que pode me ajudar é uma forma de ignorar o "?v=#####" após a extensão:

```js
$("img[src='/img/exemplo.png?v=#####']").attr('src', "/novapasta/img/novaimagem.png");
```

o Exemplo acima não funciona devido ao "?=#####".

Comment: sua pergunta está um pouco confusa, coloque dados que expliquem melhor, e tbm inclua o código javascript do que já tentou

Comment: OBS: Não posso editar o HTML diretamente, apenas inserir via <script>,  e as classes citada ("none") cuja imagem contem o src citado  podem estar em posições aleatórias.

Comment: Não consegui entender... o que deve haver no source para que seja encontrado?

Comment: Se um "src" das <img> dentro de <li> de classes determinadas possuem certa palavra, caso sim substituir o src por outro.

No exemplo acima, a Classe determinada é "none" e a palavra que precisa ser encontrada no "src" é "exemplo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eis a solução.

```js
$('.none img[src*="exemplo"]').attr('src', 'novo/caminho/imagem.png');
```

```html
<li class"none">
        <img src="/img/aqui-pode-mudar-exemplo.png?v=123456" alt="Imagem">
</li>
```